# Can ocLazyLoad be used to augment a controller and have access to its scope?

Tags: angularjs, oclazyload

I think I may be able to use ocLazyLoad to solve my problem, but couldn't easily determine from the documentation. I would like to do something like this:

```
MyApp.controller('page', ['$scope','$http', 'socketManager', '$ocLazyLoad',
function ($scope, $http, socketManager, $ocLazyLoad) {

    // Get custom content (list of devices)
    $scope.GetDevices = function () {
        $http({method: "get",url: "/api/devices"})
        .success(function (devices) {
            // Load the module(s) for this 
            devices.foreach(function () {
                $ocLazyLoad.load(devices.module);
            })
        })
    }
}])
```

With modules defined something like this:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
modules: [{
        name: 'DeviceType1',
        files: ['js/DeviceType1.js','views/partials/DeviceType1.html']
    }],
    // more devices
});
```

My question is once the module(s) is loaded, where is it loaded? Will the lazy loaded javascript have access to $scope, $http and socketManager? Also, if I include html files, is it rendered as part of the controller?

Comment: $ocLazyLoad is normally use to load codes before running controller.